# Magnet links don't open in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bittorrent

When I click magnet links in chrome nothing happens. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\magnet` has qBittorrent set correctly. When I edit `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State` I don't find `magnet`, `protocol_handler`, `excluded_schemes` or anything similar. I only have one profile on Chrome. The only way for me to use magnet links is to copy-paste them into my torrent client, which kind of defeats the purpose of magnet links. How do I fix this?

Comment: Uninstall qBitTorrent completely, preferably with a third-party like Revo Uninstaller Free, that'll make sure there are no leftovers. After that, re-install it by downloading the installer from the editor's website and nowhere else. You'll be prompted to make it your default application for torrents and magnets. Click OK or Yes, and proceed with install. You should be home-free after that. Chrome has a problem with .magnet and .torrent files anyway.